# Left-right spacing of parentheses with DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: spacing, delimiters, mathtools

I know that `\big` and similar commands cause an incorrect spacing between the delimiter and their contents, and they should be replaced with `\bigl` and so on.
I've defined some commands with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, but it seems to me that this macro doesn't use the left-right distinguished variants of `\big` (and the like) but the generic `\big` command.
The `mathtools` manual doesn't cover this question, so I ask you.
How can I make `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` with `\bigr` and `\bigl`?

For example, I have defined

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inner}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{{#1},{#2}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parentheses}{(}{)}
```

but I don't know, using `\norm[\big]{x}` whether it will be expanded as `\big\lVert{x}\big\rVert` or `\bigl\lVert{x}\bigr\rVert`.
Maybe `\rVert` and `\lVert` already take care by themselves of the correct spacing, but there's still the last one with `(` and `)`.

Comment: This is more of a general question, I don't have an issue on a particular piece of code. Anyway, I'll post an example.

Comment: Actually, `mathtools` will translate `\norm[\big]{x}` into `\mathopen{\big\lVert}x\mathclose{\big\rVert}`. And `\bigl\lVert` is defined to do `\mathopen{\big\lVert}` (similarly for `\bigr`), so it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to worry about this, behind the scenes `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` converts `\big` into `\bigl` and `\bigr`, that is the reason why we only mention `\big` in the manual. And also why if you want to make your own scaling macro, you'll need three versions for it to work with a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` construction